# golang как правильно расположить файлы и папки в проекте

Tags: golang

Как правильно расположить файлы и папки в проекте? Например, папка zzz - это корневая папка. Разумеется, это простой пример для простого сайта. В языке **golang** как правильно расположить файлы и папки? Спасибо.

```
zzz
-css
--style.css
-js
--script.js
-img
--photo.jpg
-index.html
```

Comment: Golang'у без разницы, единственное что тут может быть, это общие рекомендации, но к языку они никакого отношения не имеют.

Comment: Уважаемый vnn198, спасибо Вам большое! Значит жесткой привязки к папкам, как в ASP.NET MVC (Views, Controllers, Models)  нет. Еще раз спасибо!